# Facebook restrict posts to fanpage

Tags: facebook, wordpress, target-audience

I have a wordpress multisite (.nl, .be & .fr).

To post on a facebook page, I have installed [SNAP plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/) and created facebook app for every language.

I need to restrict the post per language. For example: French post needs to be viewable to France and French Belgium and not to Dutch Belgium.

How can I restrict posts per language? Can I restrict it via app or do I need to add extra parameter(targeting) when sending the post to facebook?

Sincerely,

Itouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target post based on multiple targeting options through the web UI or through the API when creating a post.

**THROUGH THE WEB UI**

[image: Here it shows how to configure post targeting through the UI]

Link to the doc: https://www.facebook.com/business/a/page-posting-tips

**THROUGH THE API**

If you want to do it through the API, you should check out the page/feed endpoint and the targeting / news feed targeting options.

[image: Explanation of how to use the targeting parameters]

Link to the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed